# React Native, how to make redux state false again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created a view cart in which I show total price and view cart button, when I add item it makes condition true and display that cart below in every screen, but when I click view cart it's not making it false again, how can I do this? can someone check my code and tell me please. Below is my code

Viewcart.js

```
<View>
        {this.props.show && this.props.items.length > 0 ? (
          <View style={styles.total}>
            <Text style={styles.totaltext}>Total:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.priceTotal}>{this.props.total}</Text>
            <View style={styles.onPress}>
              <Text
                style={styles.pressText}
                onPress={() => {
                  RootNavigation.navigate("Cart");
                  this.props.show;
                }}
              >
                View Cart
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    show: state.clothes.show,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    showCart: () => dispatch(showCart()),
  };
};
```

reducer.js

```
if (action.type === SHOW_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.addedItems;
    if (addedItem.length === 0) {
      return {
        ...state,
        show: state.showCart,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...state,
        show: action.showCart,
      };
    }
  }
const initialstate = {
  showCart: false
}
```

action.js

```
export const showCart = (id) => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_CART,
    showCart: true,
    id,
  };
};
```

Comment: I think you need to write a `hideCart` function and trigger it in the `onPress` function in your component if the `show` state is true

Comment: I tried but it hide that component but also clear the cart

Comment: I used action `export const showCartOff = () =>{return{type: SHOW_CARTOFF,  isCart : true}}` then in reducer ` if(type === ShOW_CARTOFF){return{...state,isCart: action.Cart}}` initial state `isCart:true`

Comment: in export const showCart = (id) ={} you set it to true, where do you set it to false ?

Comment: In initial state

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I also made a different action for it, it hide that Viewcart but also clear the cart

Comment: `export const showCartOff = () => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_CARTOFF,
    isCart: false,
  };
};`

Comment: ` if (action.type === SHOW_CARTOFF) {
    return {
      ...state,
      show: action.isCart,
    };
  }`

Comment: And console.log the prop you get for show ?

Comment: haha guess what? i didn't put ...state in showCartOff reducer

Comment: So that sorts it out right ?

Comment: now it hide but also for all screens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223206/discussion-between-kanwarjeet-singh-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the chat the requirement is to toggle this when exiting the screen so the easiest way to do that is to use the lifecycle methods.

To hide use componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.props.showCartOff(); 
}
```

to show use component

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  this.props.showCart();
}
```